# Sizing an empty JFrame to a specific size

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jlabel

I have a frame with a border layout that includes a panel with a border layout at its center that has a label in its center that presents images.

Another thread is accessing that label to portray images that can be seen as a video - this works.
However, the frame itself is sized this way every time:
https://prnt.sc/116grry
I have to resize it manually to show the image every time I run the program.

SetPreferredSize doesn't change or do anything to achieve what I want.
The code:
https://gist.github.com/IshayKom/d06f40980fe42f96e28acdf1422b9e4f

Is there any way to initiate the frame at a specific size before it gets the images?

Comment: 1) *"The code:"* For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). In case it's not obvious, code should be ***here*** rather than at some external link. 2) *"Is there any way to initiate the frame at a specific size before it gets the images?"* Sure, but forget the frame for a minute and think about the component which will be displaying the images. Guessing it's a `JLabel`? Put a transparent image inside it, of the same size as expected later. Add all the components around it, then `pack()` the `JFrame` to the exact right size.

Comment: You are calling method `pack()`. Do you understand what that method does? Since you are already calling method `pack()`, I suggest calling method `setPreferredSize()` on `jPanel1` (and keep the call to method `pack()`).

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for `.setMinimumSize` instead. `setPreferredSize` does not provide constraints and can thus be changed by other components such as the container that is used to show the image.

Comment: In the OP's code, he is calling method `pack()`. Will `setMinimumSize()` force a limit even when calling `pack()`?

Comment: @Abra yes. As per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack-- . "The resulting width and height of the window are automatically enlarged if either of dimensions is less than the minimum size as specified by the previous call to the `setMinimumSize` method."

Comment: setMinimumSize isn't good enough in this case, since I need the user to be able to adjust it manually based on their PC's resolution